# Broken upgrade from Spring security 3.2.7 to 4.0.1

Tags: spring-security, spring-data

After replacing Maven dependencies for the newer spring-security-[core|config|data|web] in the pom, the following @PreAuthorize code that used to work in version 3.2.7 now failed with AccessDeniedException.

```
public interface NotificationRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Notification, String> {

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('Administrator')")
<S extends Notification> S save(S notification);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Please change `hasRole('Administrator')` to `hasAuthority('Administrator')` :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('Administrator')")
<S extends Notification> S save(S notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('Administrator')")
Notification save(@P("notification") Notification notification);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I found the problem and will post an answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

Spring security internally uses "ROLE_" as the prefix. We create and check roles without this prefix and it works in version 3.2.7 but fails in version 4.0.1. The fix is to create roles with the prefix "ROLE_". The check can be with or without this prefix.